# Erro no CORS Ionic 5.2 - API PHP

Tags: php, ionic, api, cors

Estou tentando conectar o meu aplicativo com uma API em PHP.

Possuo o seguinte código em Ionic em que a autenticação é feita por Token:

```
login(data:IUsuario) {
    let tokenBasic = btoa(data.usuario + ":" + data.senha);
    let headerBasic = {
      "headers": { 
        'Authorization': "Basic " + tokenBasic,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache'
      }
    };
    return this.http.get<any>(this.url + '/AppLogin', headerBasic);
  }
```

Na minha API em PHP o código já contém os headers para o CORS:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');

echo json_encode((object) array( 'Auth'=> 'true', 'Data'=>'04/08/2019', 'Usuario'=> 'teste'));
?>
```

Porém ao efetuar qualquer consulta pelo navegador, obtenho o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No network:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Caro Gustavo, parece que esta usando um FW de rotas, porque a url não é final .php, então provavelmente seus headers nem foram enviados, com os detalhes da pergunta nem tem como lhe ajudar, tem que explicar direito o que fez para conseguirmos lhe ajudar

Comment: Guilherme, no caso estou utilizando o framework Codeigniter no PHP, mas o trecho do  código PHP que mencionei, eu quis apenas simplificar acessando somente ele (teste.php) sem rotas, para assim que funcionar os headers neste arquivo eu aplico em todo o framework.

Comment: Pela resposta do app não funcionaram não, faça o teste abrindo a URL diretamente via navegador, provavelmente alguma coisa falhou no seu back-end